# Is it Possible to Send an Email from XNA?

Tags: c#, email, xna, xbox360

I'm using XNA to develop a game and I need to send a confirmation email from my game.
Is it possible to send an email from XNA? If so, please post example code.

Answer (score 4):

It is **impossible** to send emails from the XNA Framework if your game is running on the ***Xbox 360***. There is no Internet access allowed on the Xbox 360 - all network traffic goes through Xbox LIVE or System Link. There is also (consequently) no API for sending emails included in the Xbox 360 XNA Framework.

---

If your game is running under ***Windows***, you *can* include a reference to [`System.Net.Mail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) and then use [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4971yhhc.aspx) and [`MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t22a8ww.aspx) to send an email. For example:

```cs
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
    "sender@example.com",                // From
    "recipient@example.com",             // To
    "Email Message",                     // Subject
    "Hello!");                           // Body

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.example.com");
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

client.Send(message);
```

For more information, see [the examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0y6s613.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The `System.net.mail` namespace should do you fine.  Use `SmtpClient` to connect to a mail server and then `MailMessage` to actually create the message.